# Retrieve ModelForm pk after save

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Models:

```
class Users(models.Model):  
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Event(models.Model):
    event_admin = models.ForeignKey(Users)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event_date = models.DateField()
    event_time = models.TimeField()
    event_notes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

View:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':        
    EventForm = CreateEventForm(request.POST,prefix = "EventForm")
    UserForm = UserInfoForm(request.POST, prefix = "UserForm")        
    if EventForm.is_valid() and UserForm.is_valid():            

        UserForm.save()

        #Problem is here
        retrieveID= UserForm.id

        Event1 = EventForm.save(commit=False)            
        Event1.event_admin= retrieveID
        Event1.save()
```

I have 2 modelforms posting to 1 form. After the 1st one saves, im trying to get its id/pk to save as a foreign key field in the second form. However, i get an error that the attribute doesnt exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`UserForm.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) would *return a newly created object*, get it:

```
obj = UserForm.save()
```